# Determining size of grid cells created by vector grid tool of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, data, vector-grid

I am working with QGIS 1.8.0 and Im making a vector grid on a map. Does someone know how big are the squares if the grid settings look like in the picture?

[image: vector grid settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grid is set to 0.01x0.01 degrees, as stated in the parameters section of the form.

For the area you have, I would increase to full degrees in the first try.